# how to hygieia application in Debug mode

Tags: debugging, dashboard, hygieia

I have setup Hygieia (https://github.com/capitalone/Hygieia) in my local machine and when i started the app from command prompt , I am able to see the dashboard in my browser, as required.

Details about my workspace

1)I am using STS ide

2)for running/starting the application(as mentioned in the documentation).

I use windows-command prompt, and use command like (eg)
j`ava -jar api.jar --spring.config.location=C:\[path to]\Hygieia\api\api.properties`

I wanted to see the application working in debug mode when i start any module (say for eg., i wanted to debug and see how data is collected and inserted while running the module:- Collector-AWS).

Could you please let me know how would I debug the application -module (or to run the application in debug mode and inspect values ) inside IDE or any other way.

I tried the way `{Debug as->Java Application}` as mentioned in some other solutions but that didn't work.

kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

Modify your command to add -Xdebug flag. like this:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n \ -jar api.jar --spring.config.location=C:\[path to]\Hygieia\api\api.properties
```